# rails carrierwave + S3 + json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, amazon-s3, carrierwave, amazon-cloudfront

I have a rails4 app that using `carrierwave` with `S3` and `cloudfront`. I only have problem with the fallback image. When I'm using `html` response (`<%= image_tag user.profile.avatar.url(:base_thumb), class: "profile-index-avatar" %>`) with the helper everything works fine, but can't figure it out how to make it work with `json` response.

If I check out the html (built from json) in production on the root page the code is:

1st jbuilder: `<img src="https://example.com/small_thumb_default.png">`

2st jbuilder: `<img src="https://example.com/assets/small_thumb_default.png">`

None of these are working.

On the top of this if I go let's say to the users page then it tries to get pic like:

1st jbuilder: `<img src="https://example.com/users/small_thumb_default.png">`

2nd jbuilder: `<img src="https://example.com/users/assets/small_thumb_default.png">`.

What should I change?

jbuilder 1st version

```
json.array! @other_notifications do |notification|
  ..
  json.profile_image_url notification.sender.profile.avatar.url(:small_thumb)
  ...
end
```

jbuilder 2nd version

```
json.array! @other_notifications do |notification|
  ..
  if notification.sender.profile.avatar_url == "default.png"
    json.profile_image_url "assets/small_thumb_default.png"
  else
    json.profile_image_url notification.sender.profile.avatar.url(:small_thumb)
  end
  ...
end
```

uploader

```
process :resize_to_fit => [400, 400]

version :base_thumb do
  process resize_to_fill: [85, 85]
end

version :small_thumb, :from_version => :base_thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [40, 40]
end

def default_url
  [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the file in question is inside `app/assets/` folder, files inside that folder are being precompiled by default and a random digest is being added on the end of the filename. For the described behavior to work your  `small_thumb_default.png` file should be placed inside `public/` folder, so it doesn't get a digest appended on precompile. Either that or you should avoid using HTML, do it the Rails way:

```
# AVOID THIS
<img src="small_thumb_default.png"/>
#THIS IS PREFERABLE
<%= image_tag 'small_thumb_default.png' %>
```

This way you will get your view rendered with the precompiled filename.